# Should bribery be explicitly forbidden?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

I saw a question today from a new user offering access to a project's source code in return for an answer to their question. I've never seen something like this before, so it's probably quite rare. But out of curiosity, I tried to find any mention of it in the rules, and failed. This practice is at best tacky, and at worst could undermine the way this site works if it became widespread. Should it be explicitly called out in the code of conduct or terms of service?

Comment: OK, so the bribery is "I'll give you my code if you solve my problem"? If so, I don't really think it's a very effective way to bribe people - if somebody can solve the problem with the code, they'd very likely not need that code themselves. Also, if the code already has a problem, then is it really *that* valuable? I'm trying to wrap my head around how this is supposed to work.

Comment: It said something like, “I’ll give you the code for an Instagram clone if you answer my question.” The question had no apparent connection to the Instagram clone.

Comment: That sounds slightly more reasonable...except if the Intagram clone was useful, we wouldn't be talking about an "instagram clone" but that thing. There have been Facebook clones, Twitter clones, Instagram clones, MySpace clones, etc since those became popular. And none of the clones have replaced the services they tried to emulate. Heck, I worked for a company that made one of these. Not by our choice but, hey, the customer was paying. You've not heard of that product, either, I assure you. So, I'm going to say that the Instagram clone wouldn't be a huge success either.

Comment: I'm with @VLAZ - I'm not sure if "I give you more code" is bribery or treat :) Realistically I don't see what could be plausible post-answer payment for an answer... I can see bounty as a potential option, but clearly in such case it is better to wait till bounty at least will show up on the question...

Comment: How is offering something of value to pay someone to perform a service *bribery* ?  The offer isn't being made to induce a public, or private, official to do something that they shouldn't ought to do.  Sure, the thing offered is of very little value, but it's an attempt to *pay* not to *bribe*.  It's called *commerce* !  And, arguably, the source code is worth more than the shiny reputation points often offered as bounties on questions - and no-one calls those *bribes*.

Comment: [I found another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68410198/8384089)  This time, someone is actually offering money for it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Forgot to come back and respond before, but you’re absolutely right. Bribery is not the right word. I found it tacky and used a word with negative connotation, which was putting unnecessary bias on what I was actually asking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be honest, I'm less concerned with the bribery aspect of the question, and more interested in its topicality.  If it's off-topic, it really doesn't matter what the OP offers in compensation; it should be closed and shut down, no questions.

In general though, those kinds of things can just be...edited out of a question.

Answer (score 14):

It's information that doesn't help answer a question and we already don't allow that so...

- the source code is vital to the question or answer - vote to close the question as unclear or downvote and vote to delete the answer as it's useless.
- the offer is in a comment - flag the comment as it adds nothing to the Q&A
- the offer is in the question or answer - edit it out if it adds nothing and flag the post if the information is reinstated.